# What to do when a User asks a question in Answer, which should have been a comment, when the User doesn't have comment privilege?

Tags: discussion

It has happened a few times where someone asked a question and there is some very obvious detail missing that **has** to be asked. And a User who doesn't yet have comment privilege comes by and asks for that detail in the Answer section.

I have flagged such answers before, and they do get removed. But once a User told me that he knows he should have posted as a comment but the user wants to help and hence the answer.

My question is should that Answer be flagged? When clearly the User means well?

Comment: Of course it should be flagged. Just because someone did not earn the (very low) rep requirement for a feature does not mean they get a free pass to ignore the rules.

Comment: You take them out back and put them down.

Comment: @l4mpi it would be hard for them to earn if they get flagged for  valid and helpfull questions.

Comment: @SvenB what? Flagging a users answer that should not have been posted as an answer does not restrict their ability to post an actual answer, or a useful question, or suggest an edit, or earn a bounty. It does not stop them from earning reputation, and it does not remove existing reputation (except for any upvotes the non-answer might have gotten - but it restores any lost rep through downvotes as well, which are much more likely on such posts). Your argument sounds like saying "giving a warning to a soccer player for playing with their hand makes it hard for them to legally score a goal".